# WSO2 identity server - Trigger SMS and Email OTP outside the login scope

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

If we enable SMS and Email OTP as dual factor authentication on WSO2 identity server for the login operation, can the same OTP configuration be called outside the login scope? for example on a certain event, we want to send an OTP, how can we call IS OTP feature in this case?
Any API available? or library? etc.

Answer (score 1):

WSO2 IS product doesn't have an inbuilt SMS/Email OTP sending and verifying API to be used as a securing mechanism of a transaction. The existing OTP validation can be used as an MFA step in application login flows.

However, you can try the following customization to configure email/sms otp REST API

1. https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-otp-integration-endpoints/blob/main/docs/instructions.md
2. https://medium.com/identity-beyond-borders/integrate-email-otps-to-your-applications-with-the-wso2-identity-server-ad619db2cd16 this explains the REST API usages

Comment: Thank you. Will the above work for all IS versions?

Comment: One more question, the email / sms configuration made on login will be the same one applied using the given library? in other words, if the user disable the otp, and the api was called, the otp will not be sent?

Comment: This was introduced in IS-5.10.0. It should be supported from 5.10.0 onwards. You can give it a try to check whether APIs work with previous IS versions too :)

Comment: Hi i followed the steps described under https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-otp-integration-endpoints/blob/main/docs/instructions.md for both SMS and email on the identity server 6.1.0. For the SMS, the API to generate otp returns 200 with a transaction id, but the sms is not received (i am using nexmo) and no error in the logs, i even tried with the same configuration as the tutorial and it was not received. can you help?

Comment: as for the email, whenever i try to call the generate api i get the following error: Authorization failure. Authorization information was invalid or missing from your request. But the bearer token is valid and it works fine with the sms otp. Can you help please?

Comment: Nexmo config used: 
        <inline>{"api_key":"xx",
            "api_secret":"xx",
            "from":"NEXMO",
            "to":{{mobile}},
            "text":{{body}}
            }</inline>
    </mapping>
    <to eventAdapterType="http">
        <property name="http.client.method">httpPost</property>
        <property name="http.url">https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json</property>
    </to>
</eventPublisher>

Comment: i solved the email issue by grouping the tenant context of both sms and email together: [tenant_context.rewrite]
custom_webapps=["/api/identity/sms-otp/v1/", "/api/identity/email-otp/v1/"]